# Question on proof of number of solutions of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

The proof my book uses starts off by saying:

> "If the system has exactly one solution or no solutions, then there is nothing to prove",

and then continues on by assuming there is an infinite number of solutions.

**My question is:** Why does this mean that there is nothing to prove?

Comment: Well, what is the proof trying to prove?

Comment: It really depends what you're proving.

Comment: It's a proof of the number of solutions of a linear system...so proving that a linear system must have exactly one, zero, or infinitely many solutions

Comment: Does the proof *assume* infinite solutions, or does it assume *more than one* solution, and go on to demonstrate that this leads to infinite solutions?

Comment: It assumes more than one. Nevermind my original question though, at this point I've figured it out

Answer (score 1):

As Joffan says, I highly doubt the proof assumes the existence of infinitely many solutions. The point is that if a system $AX=b$ has two solutions $X_1$ and $X_2$, then $A(\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2)=\lambda AX_1+(1-\lambda)AX_2=\lambda b+(1-\lambda)b=b$ for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$. Hence each $\lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda)X_2$ is also a solution.